# Batch Script to remove Specials Charcters

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to create a batch file , but i am unable to find.
My Requirement is below.

1) i have some group of text files like Text file 1 , Text File 2 , Text file 3.
2) Each text files contains Some Special Characters .
3) I want to remove those Special characters from All the Text files .
4) Some Specials characters are there which we can type it on Notepad.
5) So i need a batch file, which can search for special character by passing ASCII Value & Remove them .

Please let us know, it would be grateful.
//////  Below is text file format

```
81
2016-03-13 00:13:05 2016-03-14 00:51:39     �@  81
        101
2016-03-13 00:13:05 2016-03-14 03:02:48     xuyou       �@  
2016-03-14 03:16:06 2016-03-14 08:16:13 =M      100
2016-03-14 03:16:06 2016-03-14 08:16:13 
2016-03-14 03:16:06 2016-03-14 08:16:41     Search : ��~        100


dhfcjchjchjcdhj  �
huge files are not ready   f   okay 



                ~


                                        fd
```

Comment: Can any one help me with complete Script

Comment: Show us your efforts and we are willing to help you! Your question as it is now is nothing but a task request.

Comment: Hii ,Below is the Script i have written to eliminate Special Characters .
// Script

Comment: Can anyone suggest i am not able to post my script here , it prompts as too long

Answer (score 0):

Looks like binary data.May be he easiest way will be to use [Strings.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx):

```
strings -n 1 -a -q nottextfile >purified
```

and see if the `purified` file contains what you want.